# How do I prevent a three separate '.' characters from becoming single-character ellipsis in HTML?

Tags: html, ellipsis

I need 3 separate '.' characters directly next to each other, but HTML converts them into a single-character ellipsis.  How do I prevent this?

Comment: HTML doesn't convert three periods to an ellipsis on its own. Please show you code.

Comment: Are you using a CMS? Some editing interfaces convert `...` to `&hellip;`